# I want to show relationship with following classes but I got these error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6, database-migration, entity-framework-migrations

```
public class Newtask
{
    [Key]
    public int TId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Estimated_days_of_work { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Enrollment> Enrollments { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Subtask> Subtasks { get; set; }
}

public class Subtask
{
    [Key]
    public int SId { get; set; }
    public string SubName { get; set; }
    public int SEstimated_days_of_work { get; set; }
    public int NewtaskTId { get; set; }
    public virtual Newtask Newtasks { get; set; } 
}

public class SubSubtask
{
    [Key]
    public int SsId { get; set; }
    public string SubSubTaskName { get; set; }
    public int SsEstimated_days_of_work { get; set; }
    public int NewtaskTId { get; set; }
    public int SId { get; set; }
    public virtual Newtask Newtasks { get; set; }
    public virtual Subtask Subtasks { get; set; }
}
```

Right now I have these classes, I want to show relationship between them like each task have subtask and subtask also have its subtask, but when I run the application I got these error:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_dbo.SubSubtasks_dbo.Subtasks_SId' on table 'SubSubtasks' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints. Could not create constraint or index. See previous errors.'

How can I modify this relationship?

Comment: Why not just make `Newtask.Subtasks` an `ICollection<NewTask>` ? Why do you need different types for every level in the hierarchy?

Comment: can you explain briefly where I want to do changes in classes @ardila

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your classes are making circular dependency so when you will goto delete some entities it will break up with multiple error. if you ignore on deleting the entities you can add this to your dbcontext class's model builder.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelbuilder)
{
foreach (var relationship in modelbuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes().SelectMany(e 
            => e.GetForeignKeys()))
{
    relationship.DeleteBehavior = DeleteBehavior.Restrict;
}

base.OnModelCreating(modelbuilder);
}
```

Though the proper solution is to change your business model that will not make a circular dependency.
you can change your classes this way if u don't see any problem:

```
public class Newtask
{
    [Key]
    public int TId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Estimated_days_of_work { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Enrollment> Enrollments { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Subtask> Subtasks { get; set; }
}

public class Subtask
{
    [Key]
    public int SId { get; set; }
    public string SubName { get; set; }
    public int SEstimated_days_of_work { get; set; }
    public int NewtaskTId { get; set; }
    public virtual Newtask Newtasks { get; set; } 
    public virtual Substask HasSubtask{get;set;}
}
```

and change your modelbuilder in dbset to:

```
modelbuilder.Entity(typeof (Subtask))
        .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
```